# Rails migration error: undefined method `install_helpers' for ActionController::Routing::Routes:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Got a couple of Rails 2.3.5 projects that are giving me this error when I try to run a rake db:migrate. Wondering if someone else has seen it:

undefined method `install_helpers' for ActionController::Routing::Routes:Class

Migrations used to run fine. I've got a pretty tame routes.rb but a lot of gems and plugins, one of which may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of God delete the rails_upgrade plugin and you should be ok.